# Regular expression for alphamumeric value and can contain hyphen

Tags: regex

Hi I have to validate an input that can have alpha numeric value and hyphen. Must not start with hyphen.

**example -**

> abc-456,45678999,456-788 is valid

**but**

> -2333hj-jj is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex can do it:

```
^(\w+[-]?)+$
```

Comment: if you want the max hyphens to be one you can do it like this:    ^(\w+[-]?){2}$

Answer (score 0):

```
  ^[a-zA-Z0-9][\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

`^` character specifies starting of input which is an alphanumeric character

Answer (score 0):

if you want atleast one number to be there then use like this

```
(?=.*[0-9].*)([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]?){2}
```

other wise

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-]?){2}
```